# An event to close any dialogue / fragment

Tags: sapui5

In a fragment used as a dialogue it is common to have a cancel or close button wired with a press event. For example:

```
<buttons>
    <Button text="Save" press="onSaveData" type="Accept"/>
    <Button text="Cancel" press="onCancelBtn" type="Reject"/>
</buttons>
```

I have a couple of dialogues that appear in the current view I am working on. I would like to construct the `onCancelBtn()` event function to be generic, so have one close function into which the fragment is passed and closed - I assume the fragment is accessible from the event parameter, but how? Would `.getView()` not hit the main view?

Below is my current function but this refers to a specific dialogue.

```
    onCancelBtn: function(oEvent){
        this._oConfirmDialog.close();
    },
```

How do I use oEvent to get a reference to the fragment I want to close? If anyone can point me to documentation on the oEvent so I can read up on its structure I would be grateful. I got as far as the [EventProvider](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.EventProvider.html) in the API docs but lost the path there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fully generic approach would be to traverse the control tree from the button which triggered the event to the top using methods **getParent** and **getMetadata** until you reach the containing dialog control you want to close.

Another approach I like better is the following one. Declare a custom data attribute containing the name of property holding the dialog instance at the cancel button and evaluate this attribute in a generic event handler.

```
  <Button data:name="MyDialog" text="Cancel" press="onCancelDialogPressed" type="Reject"/>
```

You can access this custom data attribute in the event handler:

```
onCancelDialogPressed : function(event) {
   var name = event.getSource().data("name");
   if (this.fragments[name]) {
       this.fragments[name].close();
   }
}
```

This works if you instantiate the dialog like this. You store the fragment under the name declared at the custom attribute.

```
openDialogPressed : function(event) {
   if (!this.fragments.MyDialog) {
        this.fragments.MyDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("..")
        this.getView().addDependent(this.fragments.MyDialog);
   }
   this.fragments.MyDialog.open();
}
```

Of course you need to declare fragments in your controller, e.g. in **onInit**:

```
this.fragments = {};
```

Comment: Interesting. Just to confirm then, in the onCancelDialogPressed  function when you refer to  `this.fragments[name]` the `[name]` does not need to be written `[data.name]` or similar?

Comment: My fault. Of course you need to obtain the name from the control's custom data. Answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks will try it and confirm.

Comment: Works! Couple of notes: I'm using XML views - had to add the `xmlns:data="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"` declaration to XML - maybe worth adding that to your question for future readers. And I modified the openDialogPressed() function by extracting the fragment setup to another function into which I pass the required dialogue name. The only hard coding of the dialogue name is in the onPress functions. Where you have `this.fragments.MyDialog` I switched to `this.fragments[passed-in-dialog-name]` thus making the setup function truly generic. Works great.

Comment: You can avoid hard coding the names of the fragment if you assign the dialog an ID and set the custom data value of the close button to the ID of the dialog. Then in the onClose method, fetch the dialog's ID `oEvent.getSource().data().dialogId` and close the dialog `this.getView().byId(sDialogId).close()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a better and cleaner way to do this - write below code at the close event:

```
onClose: function(e) {
            e.getSource().destroy();
        }
```

Comment: A bit late, but I have to state that this won't work as getSource points you to the clicked button, not the dialog. destroy() has to be called on getSource().getParent().

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thanks for the rectification.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend using the following:

```
oEvent.getSource().getParent().close();
```